# grep hiding output of command

Tags: bash, grep

I have a command like:

```
bin/deploy staging --profile my_profile | grep 'UploadError'
```

Typically

```
bin/deploy staging --profile my_profile
```

prints many log lines to console, however when doing the grep everything gets silenced. Is there a flag I can use to unsilence the log outputs?

Basically print out what the command typically prints to console and also do the grep.

The purpose of the grep is i have some logic to handle an UploadError during a deploy. And the reason I'd like to print the full output is that I'd like to see what is going on during the deploy and not suppress the logs.

Currently if the grep does not find the string nothing is printed.If it does something like the following is printed:

```
[web] UploadError

[worker] UploadError
```

If I remove grep command something like the following is printed to console:

```
[web] INFO: Uploading archive to s3 location: my-app/app-27b50-
170829_133831-stage-170829_133831.zip
[web] INFO: Creating AppVersion app-27b50-170829_133831-stage-
170829_133831
[web] WARNING: Deploying a previously deployed commit.
[web] Uploading my-app/app-27b50-170829_133831-stage-
170829_133831.zip to S3. This may take a while.
[web] Upload Complete.
```

So what I'm trying to do is do the grep, and no matter if the string is found or not also print the original command's output to console.

Comment: please edit your Q to show your expected output. `grep` is designed as a flter, what would be purpose of keeping all the regular output? How would you know what has been flagged as a problem.. Why not just remove `|grep 'UploadError'`? Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @shellter - updated my post.

Comment: @HosseinK, hope below example can help you, I see you updated your question few minutes ago, basically if you use `tee /dev/tty` before `grep`, you still can show program log also you can grep whatever you want

Comment: could you use a shell script that injects vt100 escape sequences to highlight the `grep` search targets in colored/bold text with colored background? Otherwise, some good advice below. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically print out what the command typically prints to console and also do the grep.

I don't believe there's a way for grep to do this, but the greplike tool [ack](https://beyondgrep.com) has the `--passthru` option for this exact reason.  It will output all lines from its input, as well as highlighting the matches that it finds.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @Andy

Answer (score 5):

> `/dev/tty`
>
> Associated with the process group of that process, if any. It is
>   useful for programs or shell procedures that wish to be sure of
>   writing messages to or reading data from the terminal no matter how
>   output has been redirected. It can also be used for applications that
>   demand the name of a file for output, when typed output is desired and
>   it is tiresome to find out what terminal is currently in use. In each
>   process, a synonym for the controlling terminal

**For example**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cal | tee /dev/tty | grep -i august
    August 2017       
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
       1  2  3  4  5  
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12  
13 14 15 16 17 18 19  
20 21 22 23 24 25 26  
27 28 29 30 31        

    August 2017
```

**Save in variable**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ myvar=$(cal | tee /dev/tty | grep -i august)
    August 2017       
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
       1  2  3  4  5  
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12  
13 14 15 16 17 18 19  
20 21 22 23 24 25 26  
27 28 29 30 31        

akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ echo $myvar
August 2017
```

**You can further check variable likebelow**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ myvar=$(cal | tee /dev/tty | grep -i september)
    August 2017       
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
       1  2  3  4  5  
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12  
13 14 15 16 17 18 19  
20 21 22 23 24 25 26  
27 28 29 30 31        

akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ [ -z "$myvar" ] && echo "Not found" || echo "Found september"
Not found
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Akshay, however when I try that I get:

    tee: /dev/tty: No such device or address

Comment: @HosseinK, ok if does not exist then you may create like this, become root user then `mknod /dev/tty_mine c 5 0; chmod 666 /dev/tty_mine; chown root.root /dev/tty_mine` and then `cal | tee /dev/tty_mine | grep -i august`, hint do `ls -ltr /dev/ -1`, you will find many `tty`